# Using R how can I produce and plot the biodiversity of three zones across 3 sites?

Tags: r

My data set is large, this is an example dataset with all the different variables, data collection was replicated over 7 years, with it being taken once every 2 years. 2013-2019. There are 3 reef sites 1, 2 ,3. At each reef site there are three zones c, s, f (crest, slope and flat). I wish to compare the biodiversity in the the zones through a statistical test such as Simpsons diversity index, would this be possible to plot all three sites on 1 figure or would it be better to do this over 3 figures?

```
> dput(egdata)
structure(list(Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Zone = c("c", "c", "f", 
"f", "f", "c", "s", "s", "c", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "f", "f", 
"f", "f", "s", "s", "s", "s", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", 
"f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", "s", "s", "c", "s", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "s", "s", "s", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
"s", "s", "c", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", 
"s", "s", "s", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f"), 
    Species = c("Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", 
    "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Ctenochaetus striatus", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", 
    "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis analis", "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis analis", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", 
    "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Ctenochaetus striatus", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", 
    "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis analis", "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis analis", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Chaetodon semeion", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chaetodon semeion", 
    "Chromis analis", "Chromis analis", "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", 
    "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Chromis analis", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis analis", "Chromis xanthura", "Ctenochaetus striatus", 
    "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Ctenochaetus striatus", "Amblyglyphidodon curacao", 
    "Amblyglyphidodon leucogaster", "Chaetodon semeion", "Chromis analis", 
    "Chromis analis")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-93L))
```

Comment: What do you want to plot? What should your plots show in the end? Do you just want to see which species was found in which area? Without purpose and with this nonsensical data snippet (it's 6 times the same entry), it's hard to find out what you want to do.

Comment: yeah im sorry about the data  i couldnt do the whole set as it was so large and dput(head(fishdata)) was what outputted it i meant to have that before the data snippet in my post. I wish to compare the biodiversity of different reef zones, C was crest, S was slope and, F was flat. these are just sections of a reef system. I want to see if there is a change in biodiversity in the different zones. I also wish to compare these differences across the sites. does this make sense?

Comment: so i want to plot site/location along the x axis and biodiversity along the y axis

Comment: Ok, I think I can somehow imagine what you want to do. I assume each of your plots belongs to one reef zone only? And you want to combine all of the plots within one reef zone? (I.e., each plot is just a sample of the Zone and you want to add all species of all plots of each zone to have the total species richness of that zone?)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot the total number of species observed during the period of 3 years, you can summarize the data as follows:

```
require("dplyr")
dat <- data %>%
  group_by(Site, Zone) %>%
  summarize(Species = n_distinct(Species))
```

How you plot it then depends on what you want---barplots, for example?

```
require("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = dat, aes(fill = Site, y = Species, x = Zone)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

alternatively:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Site, y = Species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = "forest green")+
  facet_wrap(~Zone)
```

Of course, this is all customizable; however, we would need a bit more information on how exactly the result should look like...

Comment: hi thanks for your help, i believe that would tell me species richness, although this will be helpful to know i was trying to produce biodiversity readings, eg using simpsons diversity index or shannons diversity index – also was thinking to at first produce a figure using the years as replications, so  plotting mean biodiversity against location.

Comment: Yes, this would give you alpha diversity. If you want to use beta diversity, you would have to think about what to compare (because Shannon and similar indexes, i.e., beta diversity, requires comparing sites)

Comment: If you want to compare beta diversity among sites, you would have to display it as a matrix/heat map (in case you want to compare every site with every other site), or you could compare adjacent sites. The latter one would be interesting when the sites are placed on a line or gradient...

Comment: what do you mean by placed on a line or gradient? are you referring to how its plotted or the physical locations of the sites.

Comment: Yes, if the sites are located in fixed spatial or elevational distances along a line/ transect in the physical world, you could compare adjacent sites. You could also calculate beta-diversity with distance in general (beta diversity as a function of distance). However, it is your data and you'll know best what you want to find out. My point was just that you cannot calculate Shannon per Site and year. You have to compare that site to another site, so my question would be if you want to calculate Shannon between specific sites/zones or as a matrix where every site is compared with every other

Comment: okay makes sense. I'm not too sure, so is it possible to would it be possible to produce a figure comparing the biodiversity at the 3 zones at the 3 sites (its the same zonation at each as each zone refers to a section of reef). And would this be possible to produce a figure for each years data (so just run it on each years data). as i could then compare the change in biodiversity/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tapply()` to create a matrix of location/site and biodiversity. But you'll need a function for the computation of biodiversity. Did you just want the number of different species or the entropy of species or something else?

This would be for number of different ones. You can change it to your desired function:

```
biodiv = function(species.vector){
   return(length(unique(species.vector))
}
```

Then, you can just use this as the aggregating function:

```
mat = tapply(df$Species, by=list(df$Zone,df$Site), FUN=biodiv)
```

Once you have this matrix, you can directly plot it using `barplot(m)`.

Comment: I'm trying to find its biodiversity through simpsons diversity index

Comment: Then just implement it in the `biodiv` function. It gets a `species.vector`, which is a vector of characters naming the species. `table(species.vector)` gives you the frequency for each species in a vector, `length(species.vector)` gives you the total number of animals. From that you can compute simpson's quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Based on what I now think you have in mind:
Reorganize your data and make an abundance matrix (from how your data looks like, you sampled species abundance data, I guess?)

```
require("dplyr")
year <- 2013
dat <- data[data$Year == year,]

# species abundance matrix
abundanceMatrix <- matrix(nrow = length(unique(dat$Site)),
                   ncol = length(unique(dat$Species)))
rownames(abundanceMatrix) <- unique(dat$Site)
colnames(abundanceMatrix) <- unique(dat$Species)

for(i in 1:NROW(abundanceMatrix)){
  for(j in 1:NCOL(abundanceMatrix)){
    abundanceMatrix[i, j] <- length(dat$Site == rownames(abundanceMatrix)[i] & dat$Species == colnames(abundanceMatrix)[j])
  }
}
```

With this, you can now calculate diversity indices easily, e.g., using the function `betadiver` or `diversity`, like:

```
diversity(abundanceMatrix, index = "shannon")
```

Obviously, you'll have to choose an appropriate measure of beta diversity, depending on your data (you could also transform the `abundanceMatrix` to presence/absence data (e.g, `presenceMatrix <- as.numeric(abundanceMatrix >= 1)`)).
Read the [Vegan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/diversity-vegan.pdf) and the function documentations for details.

Depending on what exactly you want to know, you can further subset your data set (e.g., selecting a certain zone before generating the matrix). You can also compute multiple-sites dissimilarity, using the functions provided by packages such as `betapart`.

```
require("betapart")
beta.multi(presenceMatrix, index.family = "sorensen")
```

will return Simpson and Sorenson indices, as well as a nestedness component (see the [betapart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betapart/betapart.pdf) documentation).
Maybe you want to subset your data to get one presence/absence matrix per year and zone and then calculate the Sorenson index. For each year, you could then plot the Sorenson indices for the various zones as bars in a barplot. If this is what you intended.

I think the above shown code to calculate presence/absence or abundance matrices will help you get your data in a usable format. All R functions required to make a meaningful analysis of your data are explained in the linked package documentations.

Those are the tools required; how exactly you use them to pursue your scientific goal is up to you. Have fun.

Comment: Hi Manuel, thanks a lot I think this is a lot of help. Can you briefly explain what this is doing/why I'm doing it. year <- 2013
dat <- data[data$Year == year,]

Comment: ```dat <- data[data$Year == year,]``` generates a new data frame calles ```dat``` with only entries of the original data frame for which Year equals to 2013 (or what ever was set as "year" above). Similarly, you can create an other data frame that contains only entries from a specific zone ```zone <- "c"``` and then ```dat <- data[data$Zone == zone,]```. Or both: ```dat <- data[data$Zone == zone & data$Year == year,]```. Then you can calculate e.g. Sorenson after changing the year and zone and compare what the differences are, e.g. between different zones.

Comment: ```> dat <- data[data$Year == year,]
Error in data$Year : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable```    was what was outputted

Comment: It works for me, maybe your data frame is not called ```data``` and you have to adjust that word in the code. You have, of course, to make sure that the name of the data frame and its columns are correct. Then it should produce no error. Using ```[rows , columns]``` to subset objects with fitting dimensions is quite basic R, so you should probably get familiar with that... Also run just ```data$Year == year``` to check if there are rows in ```data$Year``` (column called year in the data frame called ```data```) that meet the condition (equal to ```year```)

Comment: ```egdata$Zone == zone
Error in egdata$Zone == zone : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types```  data frame is correct as is column header

Comment: ```class(egdata)``` should give ```[1] "data.frame"``` and ```names(egdata)``` should give a vector ```[1] "Year"    "Site"    "Zone"    "Species"```, at least with your example data... If you get different output, you might have accidentally changed your data frame(?)
I can just copy ```egdata$Zone == zone``` from here, paste it in the terminal, run and get ```[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE ...```, so there should be no problem (at least with the example data you provided)

Comment: I tried closing and opening a fresh R document however this was what is produced for me                                                                                                                             ``` class(egdata)
[1] "data.frame"
> names(egdata)
[1] "Year"    "Site"    "Zone"    "Species"
> egdata$Zone == zone
Error: object 'zone' not found
> zone <- c
> egdata$Zone == zone
Error in egdata$Zone == zone : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
> ```

Comment: In ```zone <- "c"```, the c has to be in quotation marks. If it is not, R will assume it is a variable. If it is, R will assume it is a string.

Comment: Yep thanks I have managed to produce the abundance matrix however this line of code gives me an error message ```for(j in 1:NCOL(abundanceMatrix)){
+     abundanceMatrix[i, j] <- length(dat$Site == rownames(abundanceMatrix)[i] & dat$Species == colnames(abundanceMatrix)[j])
+   }
Error in i : object 'i' not found
> ```   also the abundance matrix reads N/A in all the boxes other than the column names - but I don't know if that's because this line isn't working.

Comment: ```i``` is automatically set when you run the loop as I wrote it above. It says ```for(i in 1:NROW(abundanceMatrix))```, unless you change the ```i``` there, it will iteratively assign all values between 1 and the number or rows of the abundance matrix as ```i```. In this example the exact column names are important, they should have been set via ```rownames(abundanceMatrix) <- unique(dat$Site)```. Obviously, here you will also need to change ```dat``` to how ever you named the data frame in the code you executed before.

Comment: i named it dat so that this wouldn't be an issue so its not a labelling issue. i have j in my values in the environment but no i from running ```or(i in 1:NROW(abundanceMatrix)){
  for(j in 1:NCOL(abundanceMatrix)){
    abundanceMatrix[i, j] <- length(dat$Site == rownames(abundanceMatrix)[i] & dat$Species == colnames(abundanceMatrix)[j])
  }``` Are you saying i need to set i to the number of rows?

Comment: Just check for typos or missing letters. Such as in your comment, the "f" from "for" at the beginning is missing. Obviously, such things will corrupt the code...

Comment: managed to get it working, but although I've run the code, abundance matrix is full of NA values.  it contains the species names but no abundance data. as such using ```diversity(abundanceMatrix, index = "shannon")``` didn't return anything

Comment: The matrix is initialized empty and subsequently filled while running the loop. ```NROW(abundanceMatrix)```  and ```NCOL(abundanceMatrix)``` should be > 0. Then is **must** fill in something. Otherwise try replacing the capital NROW and NCOL with lower case letters...

Comment: its not filling either way,  lowercase or uppercase. this is exactly the code I've used. ```abundanceMatrix <- matrix(nrow = length(unique(dat$Site)),
                          ncol = length(unique(dat$Species)))
rownames(abundanceMatrix) <- unique(dat$Site)
colnames(abundanceMatrix) <- unique(dat$Species)

for(i in 1:nrow(abundanceMatrix)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(abundanceMatrix)){
    abundanceMatrix[i, j] <- length(dat$Site == rownames(abundanceMatrix)[i] & dat$Species == colnames(abundanceMatrix)[j])
  }```